# Implementing a calculation in join in Pig

Tags: apache-pig

New pig user. I converted mysql statements to pig and came up against the below problem. I have 2 tables which I need to join and the joined values have a calculation.I think it must be simple problem.

For example, my tables are *machine1* and *machinemeans* which I join.Could not find syntax in `Pig` manual for making calculation in join. Any suggestions?

```
    select region, os, group, f.machine, f.machine_users, f.machine_tm,
    f.machine_users - g.users_per_machine outliers,
    f.machine_tm - g.tm_per_machine    outlying_tm,
    tm_per_machine/(f.machine_tm+1) factor
    from machine1 f
    inner join machinemeans g using(region, os, group)
    order by 4, 1, 2, 3
```

Thx

Update: Thanks, WinnieNicklaus.
I tried your suggestion but I get a scalar has more than 1 row in output error. Here is my code.

```
 machine1 = LOAD 'S1'  AS (

    block:chararray,
    region:chararray,
    os:chararray,
    group:int,
    machine:int,
    machine_users:int,
    machine_tm:float
);

machinemeans = LOAD 'S2' AS (

    region:chararray,
    os:chararray,
    group:int,
    tot_machines:int,
    tot_users:int,
    users_per_machine:float,
    tm_per_machine:float,
    tm_per_user:float,
    cnt_per_block:float,
    cnt_per_user:float
);


imbalance = FOREACH (JOIN machine1 by (region,os,group), 
machine2 by   (region,os,group))    
GENERATE 
  region,os,group,
  machine1.machine,
  machine1.machine_users,
  machine1.machine_tm,
  machine1.machine_users - machinemeans.users_per_machine,
  machine1.machine_tm - machinemeans.tm_per_machine;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A single SQL query can require multiple Pig Latin statements.  The calculation you refer to is not exactly in the SQL `join`; it's really in the `select` statement, and `select ... from ...` in SQL basically corresponds to Pig's `FOREACH ... GENERATE ...`.  So do a `FOREACH` on the result of the `JOIN`.  For example:

```
result =
    FOREACH (
        JOIN table1 BY key1, table2 BY key2
    ) GENERATE
        table1.field1,
        table1.field2,
        table2.field3,
        table1.field4 - table2.field5;
```

If you need to do a calculation to obtain the join keys, but don't care about them later, you can even do

```
JOIN table1 BY (field1+field4), table2 BY myUDF(field3);
```

Comment: Edit above. Specific Error message: "Scalar has more than one row in the output."

Comment: Never mind. Had forgotten to use the :: operator in the join. It works fine now. Thanks.